# Find the solution of the differential equation that satisfies the given initial condition $~y'=\frac{x~y~\sin x}{y+1}, ~~~~y(0)=1~$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the solution of the differential equation that satisfies the given initial condition $$~y'=\frac{x~y~\sin x}{y+1}, ~~~~~~y(0)=1~$$

When I integrate this function I get 
$$y+\ln(y)= -x\cos x + \sin x + C.$$

Have I integrated the function correctly?

How do I complete the second part of the question $~y(0)=1~$

Comment: This is correct. Setting $x=0,\,y=1$ gives $C$. If you exponentiate both sides thereafter, you have $ye^y$ as a function of $x$. If you want $y$ as a function of $x$, see this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_w_function

Comment: I managed to get C=1, so I now have y+ln(y)= -xcosx +sinx +1  How do I exponentiate both sides?

Comment: Yes you have to exponentiate both sides as,$$ye^y=e^{1+sinx-xcosx}$$
So,$$y=W(e^{1+sinx-xcosx})$$refer link given by @J.G.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I'm still not sure how you get the left hand side ye^y. I understand the right hand side

Comment: @chelseathomson $e^{y+ln(y)}=e^ye^{ln(y)}=e^yy$ because $e^{ln(y)}=y$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  You might benefit from the introductory note, [How can I format mathematics here?](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to use the so-called *Separation of variables* (see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables):

1. Write $y' = \frac{dy}{dx}$
2. Do the following transformation: $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{xy \sin(x)}{y+1} \Longleftrightarrow \frac{y+1}{y} dy = x\sin(x) dx$. Now integrate both sides (with respect to the corresponding variable), arriving at
3. $\int (1 + \frac{1}{y}) dy = \int x \sin(x) dx \Longleftrightarrow y + \ln(y) = \sin(x) - x \cos(x) + C$.
4. To get the integration constant $C$, set $x = 0$ and $y = 1$, then: $1 = 0 + C \Longleftrightarrow C = 1$.
5. You'll not be able to solve the equation in 3 for the function $y = y(x)$ in terms of *elementary* functions (such as trigonometric functions, exponential/logarithmic functions etc.); But what you can do is to use the so-called *Lambert W function*, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function. Then you will get $y(x) = W(e^{\sin(x) - x \cos(x) + 1})$.

Answer (score 0):

we write the equation in the form
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{y}\right)dy=x\sin(x)dx$$
integrating we obtain
$$y+\ln|y|=\sin(x)-x\cos(x)+C$$

Comment: Copying what is already in the question and not answering what is actually asked.

Comment: you are don't sitting here to see if i have copied the answer

Comment: What? My comment points out that your post "indicates" to the OP things they already know. (But hey, Dr., we all know you do not care, so why do you suddenly pretend you do?)

Comment: the solution is a absolut value missing

Comment: Which is irrelevant since $y(0)=1$. But if this is indeed your reason for copying parts of the question (which, somehow, I doubt...), you should indicate that is is in your post.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: The form $\log|y|$ stands for a pair of solutions $\log(x)$ for $x\gt0$ and $\log(-x)$ for $x\lt0$. Since $\int\frac{\mathrm{d}y}y$ diverges at $0$, solutions rarely exist across $0$. In this case $y\gt0$ and so the integral needed is simply $\log(y)$. Note further that promoting $\log|z|$ into complex integrals is not good.

Answer (score 0):

Given that $$~y'=\frac{x~y~\sin x}{y+1}$$
$$\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x~y~\sin x}{y+1}$$
$$\implies \frac{y+1}{y}~dy=x\sin x~dx$$
$$\implies \left(1+\frac{1}{y}\right)~dy=x\sin x~dx$$
Integrating we have $$y+\log y=\int x\sin x~dx $$
$$\implies y+\log y=-~ x\cos x+\sin x~+~C\qquad \text{where $~C~$is integraating constant.}$$
Now given condition is $~~y(0)=1~~$, which gives $$1+0=0+0+C\implies C=1$$
So the solution of the differential equation that satisfies the given initial condition is $$y+\log y=-~ x\cos x+\sin x~+~1$$

---

Using integrating by parts rule:
$$\int x\sin x~dx =x\int \sin x~dx~-~\int \left(\frac{d}{dx}x~\int \sin x~dx\right)~dx$$
$$=-x~\cos x~-~\int \left(1\cdot~(-)~\cos x\right)~dx$$
$$=-x\cos x+\sin x$$